# Как сделать полосу прокрутки невидимой

Tags: android, textview

Нужно для TextView сделать невидимой полосу прокрутки или вообще убрать. В гугле ничего не нашел.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В xml-файле нужно указать `android:scrollBars="none"`